# I faced the error while search any string Magento 2

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

When I search for any string in Magento2 then there is result page showing blank. I got the exception.log file.

> "[2018-06-01 08:57:23] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1191 Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list, query was: SELECT `search_synonyms`.* FROM `search_synonyms` WHERE (MATCH (synonyms) AGAINST ('9898' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 0): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1191 Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list, query was: SELECT `search_synonyms`.* FROM `search_synonyms` WHERE (MATCH (synonyms) AGAINST ('9898' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) at /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento223/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235, PDOException(code: HY000): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1191 Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list at /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento223/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"} []
>   "

Comment: Apply index matching the column list -----  ALTER TABLE `COLUMNS ` ADD FULLTEXT(`column1`,`column2`);

Comment: COLUMNS == YOUR COLUMNS WHICH GENERATING ISSUE

Comment: does any one found solution of it?

Comment: @ChiragRajput Can you please give me your URL? Can you please check in the luma theme once?

Comment: @SunnyRahevar , Magento2 is installed in my local system (MAMP). I think the issue was due to database migration from magento1 to magento2. The answer of user payalpatel help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Okay. Actually i don't know how i solved this issue as it is four month old question and i was forgot to add the solution here. Any way , i am accept the answer of Payal Patel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check this query :

```
SELECT search_synonyms.* FROM search_synonyms WHERE (MATCH (synonyms) AGAINST ('9898' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

And give the query in database table `search_synonyms`

```
ALTER TABLE search_synonyms ADD FULLTEXT(synonyms);
```

Comment: Working great !!!! Only ran the Alter command **ALTER TABLE search_synonyms ADD FULLTEXT(synonyms);**

Answer (score 2):

**FULLTEXT** indexes are created on text-based columns `(CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns)` to help speed up queries and **DML** operations on data contained within those columns, omitting any words that are defined as stopwords.

A **FULLTEXT** index is defined as part of a **CREATE TABLE** statement or added to an existing table using **ALTER TABLE** or **CREATE INDEX**.

> Cant find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

By your query, it seems that you are attempting to search the desired data using **FULLTEXT INDEX** functionality on **NON-INDEXED** columns of your table namely `(title, detail, answer)` that is why you are getting `#1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column error`.

1. Add the **FULLTEXT INDEX** on the concerned column. You can do this simply by the following query:
   `ALTER TABLE books ADD FULLTEXT name_of_index(title,detail,answer);`
2. Or change your query by adding **"IN BOOLEAN MODE"** because **MySQL** allows to search on **FULLTEXT** non-indexed columns in this mode. So you will have to do the following:

`SELECT id, title, category_id FROM books 
 WHERE
 MATCH (title, detail, answer) 
 AGAINST ('What is mysql', IN BOOLEAN MODE)
 LIMIT 0 , 30;`

**Note :** Above code is giving a knowledge about your error you need to check how to do in magento.

I hope it helps!